# plyr / video not autoplaying when 2 vimeo videos on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, plyr, plyr.js

I have had a problem recently where I cannot autoplay / play two videos from vimeo when they are on the same page using Plyr, although they work for the youtube videos.

Here is a snippet

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
var $videoComponent = $('.jsVideoComponent');

if ($videoComponent.length) {

    $videoComponent.each(function(index) {
        var $thisComponent = $(this);
  console.log($thisComponent);
        var $thisVideo = $thisComponent.find('.jsVideo');

        // control video
        var video = plyr.setup($thisComponent.find('.jsVideo').get());

        var $button = $thisComponent.find('.jsVideoBtn');
        $button.on('click', function() {
    console.log($thisComponent);
            $thisComponent.find('.plyr').show();
            video[0].toggleFullscreen();
            video[0].play();
        });

        video[0].on('exitfullscreen', function() {
            $thisComponent.find('.plyr').hide();
            video[0].stop();
        });
    });

  }
 });
```

Comment: use flash might solve this, browser go queer when two or more video play at the same time, maybe decode costs alot, I'm not sure

Comment: @Kiwimoisi: pay attention plyr tag here on SO refer to https://github.com/hadley/plyr and not to https://github.com/sampotts/plyr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Vimeo video player

By default, when another video is played in the same browser, Vimeo player will automatically pause.

To enable the autopause behavior of Vimeo player use [vimeo setAutopause()](https://github.com/vimeo/player.js/#setautopauseautopause-boolean-promiseboolean-unsupportederrorerror):

```
player.setAutopause(false).then(function(autopause) {
    // autopause was turned off
}).catch(function(error) {
    switch (error.name) {
        case 'UnsupportedError':
            // Autopause is not supported with the current player or browser
            break;

        default:
            // some other error occurred
            break;
    }
});
```

#### Usage with Plyr

As in Plyr documentation there is no trace of "autopause" option I think the only way is to access the Vimeo player embedded.

Among [methods exposed to Plyr instance](https://github.com/sampotts/plyr#methods) there is *getEmbed()*:

> getEmbed()    —   Get the embed API to access those methods -
>   either YouTube or Vimeo.

So when Plyr instance is ready get the embedded player and apply `setAutopause(false)`:

```
plyr_instance.on('ready', function(event) {
    var player = plyr_instance.getEmbed();
    player.setAutopause(false)
});
```

#### Example:

here is a jsfiddle showing my approach: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/01f0umdz/

Comment: Beaver thank you for your approach, that does make a lot of sense. I will therefore accept this answer. Also, I do have another issue regarding multi videos on the same page using Plyr ? Maybe you could be helpful too ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48534684/plyr-video-plugin-multiple-instances

Comment: I've seen your new question, but I have no ipad to try on, sorry